Contradiction in definition of Division
I have basic questions in the very fundamental definition of division.

When we write $10\div 2$, the meaning is $10$ is divided into $2$ equal parts and how much of $10$ is distributed in each part. The answer is $5$.
But when we write $3\div 0.5$, $3$ is divided into $0.5$ equal parts and as per the rule above each part is $0.5$, so the answer should be $0.5$ right? but we say it takes $6$ parts of $0.5$ to make $3$, so the answer is $6$.

Why this contradiction of definition while dividing by fractions?

What does it mean to divide something into $r$ equal parts, when $r$ is not a positive integer? (Answer: it's a nonsense. You can only divide things into a whole number of parts.)

So you are saying 3 cannot be divided by 0.5 and its a non-sense. What a joke!

Please. I'm saying the number of parts into which you divide three can't be $0.5$. You can divide three into two parts, or three parts, or four parts, or five parts, and so on, and so forth, but not into $0.5$ parts, or minus six parts, or $\sqrt2$ parts, or $\pi$ parts, because none of those numbers makes any sense as a number of parts. You can divide three by any number you like (except zero), but you can't divide three into $r$ parts, unless $r$ is a positive integer.

I’m voting to close this question because OP refuses to engage.

An interesting question, but there is a rather fundamental issue with the phrasing. I will address the language issue at the end, but first address the mathematical non-issue.
For a start we can define $a \div b=c$ to mean the result of the division, not the process; if $a\div b=c$ then $a=c\times b$ (so $\div$ and $\times$ are inverse operations)
Then when we say $3\div 0.5$ we want the number $c$ such that $c\times 0.5 = 3$ which, in this case is 6.
Another way to consider the division by rational divisors is this: $3\div 0.5$ means we have three wholes and want to know how many halves we can make.
Three wholes is a bit like three sets, each of which has two halves so the total number of parts is $3\times 2=6$.
Getting back to the apparent contradiction in your statement - it is more of a language contradiction than a mathematical one. Dividing something in half is not the same as dividing it by one half, despite how similar the phrases may sound.
